# Check how many times files are accessed

Tags: bash, shell

I could refer to files `last access time` and sort them by

```
$ ls -ltu    total 60
drwxr-xr-x 11 me staff   352 Nov 13 20:05 1.systemOverview
drwxr-xr-x 11 me staff   352 Nov 13 20:05 3.File_IO
drwxr-xr-x  4 me staff   128 Nov 13 20:05 4.filesAndDirectories
drwxr-xr-x 37 me staff  1184 Nov 13 20:05 apue.3e
-rw-r--r--  1 me staff  4037 Nov 13 19:10 draft1.md
-rw-r--r--  1 me staff 56763 Nov 13 19:10 APUE.md
```

How could I sort them by how many times they were accessed, or how frequently they are opened?

Comment: How and where do you store the information about how many times a file was accessed?

Comment: bash doesn't keep track of the number of times accessed,,